# Porque essa função está interpretando que ouve mais de um click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho a seguinte função.

```
function getValue() {
    $("#SavePaper").click(function(e) {
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            if ( $("input[type='radio'][name='Licenciamentodeusuários']").is(':checked') ){
                valor = $('input:radio[name=Licenciamentodeusuários]:checked').val();

                if(valor == "Até") {

                    if ($("#Ate-Comercial-MF").val() != undefined) {
                        qtdUsuarios = $("#Até-Comercial-MF").val();
                        vlrSavePaper = qtdUsuarios * 0.99;
                        console.log(vlrSavePaper);
                    }
                    if ($("#Até-Educacional-MF").val() != undefined) {
                        qtdUsuarios = $("#Até-Educacional-MF").val();
                        vlrSavePaper = qtdUsuarios * 0.99;
                        console.log(vlrSavePaper);
                    }
                    if ($("#Até-Profissional-MF").val() != undefined) {
                        qtdUsuarios = $("#Até-Profissional-MF").val();
                        vlrSavePaper = qtdUsuarios * 0.99;
                        console.log(vlrSavePaper);
                    }

                    if ($("#Até-Comercial-NG").val() != undefined) {
                        qtdUsuarios = $("#Até-Comercial-NG").val();
                        vlrSavePaper = qtdUsuarios * 0.99;
                        console.log(vlrSavePaper);
                    }
                    if ($("#Até-Educacional-NG").val() != undefined) {
                        qtdUsuarios = $("#Até-Educacional-NG").val();
                        vlrSavePaper = qtdUsuarios * 0.20;
                        console.log(vlrSavePaper);
                    }
                    if ($("#Até-Profissional-NG").val() != undefined) {
                        qtdUsuarios = $("#Até-Profissional-NG").val();
                        vlrSavePaper = qtdUsuarios * 0.99;
                        console.log(vlrSavePaper);
                    }
                }else{
                    valor = valor.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
                    valor = valor.split(" ");

                    vlrSavePaper = valor[2] * 0.99;
                    console.log(vlrSavePaper);
                }
            }

         }
     });
}
```

Essa função é uma chamada de um onclick() de um checkbox, e parece que ele está executando como se fosse vários clicks, pelo meu entender de depuração do Chrome.

Esse é o retorno no Chrome

**Com 1 click**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**Com 2 clicks**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**Com 3 clicks** 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No código que colocou na pergunta, qual é a linha 59?

Comment: é o console.log de Até-Comercial-NG

Comment: Em seu `js-proposta-comercial.js` o que tem na linha 59?

Comment: console.log(vlrSavePaper); 
Isso

Comment: Se você chamar a função `getValue` três vezes, você vai associar a função no evento `click` à checkbox três vezes. *Food for thought.*

Comment: Como assim a chamar tres vezes?

Comment: A entendi... isso acabaria não afetando o valor final acredito eu